# How to get the last not null value for a column while sorting based upon a timestamp column

Tags: sql, null, vertica, notnull

Table T has columns A, B, C, TS(timestamp) with values as defined below

```
A B C    TS
d g null 3
h y gh   2
q r null 7
```

If I write a query like below:

```
SELECT * from T order by TS desc Limit 1;
```

It gives me result as:

```
A B C     TS
q r null  7
```

What I want is to never get a null value. Instead it should display the last not null value from that column, if any.

Desired result:

```
A B C   TS
q r gh  7
```

Comment: Do you know how works [LEAD/LAG function](https://learnsql.com/blog/lead-and-lag-functions-in-sql/)?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Tried it but didn't work for me. May be I am not using it the right way. Can you provide an example of the query as per the sample data I have provided. Appreciate it.

Comment: Please post what you tried, lead/lag is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try the OLAP function `LAST_VALUE( .... IGNORE NULLS) OVER ...`.
I saw that you get data that makes sense if you order by `ts` ascending in the window definition clause - I hope that is what you need ...

```
WITH
-- your input ...
indata(A,B,C,TS) AS (
          SELECT 'd','g',null,3
UNION ALL SELECT 'h','y','gh',2
UNION ALL SELECT 'q','r',null,7
)
-- real query starts here ...
SELECT
  LAST_VALUE(a IGNORE NULLS) OVER w AS a
, LAST_VALUE(b IGNORE NULLS) OVER w AS b
, LAST_VALUE(c IGNORE NULLS) OVER w AS c
, ts
FROM indata
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY ts)
ORDER BY ts DESC
LIMIT 1;
-- out  a | b | c  | ts 
-- out ---+---+----+----
-- out  q | r | gh |  7
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to fetch each column independently:

```
select (select a from T where a is not null order by TS desc Limit 1),
       (select b from T where b is not null order by TS desc Limit 1),
       (select c from T where c is not null order by TS desc Limit 1),
       (select ts from T where ts is not null order by TS desc Limit 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I guess that would be too much in case I have many such columns.